# Stop a php infinite loop-currently running

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, infinite-loop

I have a seemingly simple problem.

I was looking for an error in a php function that wouldn't return the result. So, quite stupidly, I put mail() functions in different areas of the function to see where it hangs up.

I narrowed it down to a while loop, and (quite stupidly again) decided to put the mail() function directly in the loop. Sure enough...that was the problem. The loop is infinite. I am now getting thousands upon thousands of emails and I can't get it to stop.

I am running a wordpress site hosted on a Mac. It is running the apache web server that comes with Mountain Lion Server.app.

I tried stoping the web service...emails kept pouring in. I logged out of the user...still more emails. It only stopped when I turned off the server, only to start again when I restart.

I have tried this but there are no php processes running:
[Stopping an infinite loop on a remote server PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526701/stopping-an-infinite-loop-on-a-remote-server-php)

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill the mail server queue. You will keep getting emails until all of them have been sent.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the postpix mail server que (for my mail server) or is there a php mail server que that I would need to empty?

Comment: It would be the mail server that PHP has been configured to use. If it's using the default, then you'd have to deal with whatever the `sendmail` executable shoves its mail at.

Comment: It is default. I typed: sendmail -bp. My queue is empty but the emails are still coming in.

Comment: Then your local mail server has sent them out, and you need to stop them at the destination mail server.

Comment: Yes. That was the case. they just hadn't reached my inbox. I suppose it is finished now. I stopped getting the emails. Thanks.